# Determine base URL of PHP app

Tags: php, url

I have this little piece of code which determines the base URL of PHP:

```
$root = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
if(basename(__FILE__) !== trim($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], "/\\")) {
    $root .= "/" . basename(__DIR__);
}
```

This is working for me, but are there other solutions for this "problem," or are there any cases where this would fail?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this works?

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work for one level deep working directories such as:

1. servername/admin/index.php
2. servername/sample/test.php

However, go one level deeper and it will not work. If I have **servername/one/two/index.php**, I will get a **servername/two**. It is because the **basename()** returns the working folder of the file.

I find this code useful for common applications:

```
$request = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
array_pop($request);
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . implode('/', $request);
```

It makes use of server's script name. Given the sample **servername/one/two/index.php**, it will return **/one/two/index.php**. We then remove the script from the directory using explode and popping the result, and then finally concatenating it to the server name.

Comment: Both the OP example and your example will cause a notice in a command line environment, where `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, $_SERVER is not available in CLI because no web server is present.